# Eloquent add optional condition to hasMany where foreign key is null

Tags: php, laravel

How do you add an optional/OR condition to a eloquent relationship?

E.g I want all the users comments OR where the foreign key (user_id) is NULL.

```
select * from `comments` where (`user_id` is null OR `comments`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3)) AND `status` = 1
```

In the User relationship added `orWhereNull`

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class)->orWhereNull('user_id');
}
```

But Laravel it's running:

```
select * from `comments` where `user_id` is null and `comments`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3)
```

Surprised this hasn't been asked before only thing I found similar was this:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-orwherenull-when-where-has-no-results

I tried this but it needs the model not the query builder.

```
return $this->where(function ($query){
     return $query::hasMany(Comment::class)->orWhereNull('user_id');
});
```

I'm using eager loading to fetch the comments for a list of users.

```
$users = User::with('comments')->where('active', 1)->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize this further to your need, just giving an idea on query

```php
$users = User::with('comments', function($query){
    $query->where('user_id', '=', null)->where('status', '1');
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Do not do `where('user_id', '=', null)` there is an existing method for this and is `whereNull('user_id')`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the "orWhere" is sent to the underlying query builder immediately but the foreign key constraint is added when the query is run. I couldn't work out a nice way to sort that but this workaround is fine for my use case where I'm only selecting one row at a time with this relation (granted I should probably use replace it with a getter...):

(Excuse any mistakes, changing model names for clarity):

```php
class Customer
{
    public function selectedOrCurrentWeek(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Week::class, 'id', 'selected_week_id')
            ->withDefault(function (Week $instance, Customer $parent) {
                return $instance->newQuery()
                    ->whereRaw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between start_date and end_date')
                    ->where('customer_id', $parent->id)
                    ->first();
            });
    }
```

Query log when fetching a customer by ID :-

```sql
select * from `customers` where
    `customers`.`id` = ?
    and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null
limit 1;

select * from `weeks` where
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between start_date and end_date
    and `customer_id` = ?
    and `weeks`.`deleted_at` is null
limit 1;
```

but it will run the second query once per row